# Closed form for the n-th term

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I was wondering... Is there any closed form for the partial sums of this serie?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k \frac{1}{n-1}$$

Comment: Note $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k \frac{1}{n-1} = \frac {1}{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k . $

Comment: How distracted am I! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

Notice, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\frac{1}{n-1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k$$
This A.P. $\ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k$ can be further simplified as follows
$$=\frac{1}{n-1}(1+2+3+\ldots +(n-1))$$
$$=\frac{1}{n-1}\left(\frac{(n-1)}{2}(n-1+1)\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{n-1}\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right)$$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{n}{2}}$$

Answer (score 3):

This can be simplified to $$\frac{1}{(n-1)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k$$ so it's just an arithmetic series.